# Creating error conditions and pass them back to the client

Tags: java, grails, error-handling

In my Grails web application, I have a popup dialog that allows me to input some type of Natural Language expression, that will be used to execute some action in the application.

I am currently implementing the parser in groovy, and was wondering how I go about creating error messages and returning them to the client.

I was thinking of using `<g:formRemote>` that will use ajax to send the string of text to the parser, and on successful parsing of the string, it will execute the action in the application, say to add a user to a project, usually followed by a redirect to a new page, say to show the user now part of the project.  If the parser receives a token it does not expect / recognize, or if the string is not following the correct grammar, I was to be able to create an error message and send it back to the client, allowing the user to try another command.

So far my code looks like this..

In my controller for receiving the ajax request

```
def runTemp()
{
    def tokenizer = new Tokenizer()
    def posTagger = new PartOfSpeechTagger()

    def words = tokenizer.getTokens("add user");
    def taggedWords = posTagger.tagWords(words)

    taggedWords.each{
        println"${it.word} : ${it.partOfSpeech}"
    }       
}
```

and my PartOfSpeechTagger.groovy looks like

```
package uk.co.litecollab.quickCommandParser

class PartOfSpeechTagger {

def lexicons = [
    //VERBS
    'add': PartOfSpeech.VERB,
    'new': PartOfSpeech.VERB,
    'create': PartOfSpeech.VERB,
    'view': PartOfSpeech.VERB,
    'delete': PartOfSpeech.VERB,
    'logout': PartOfSpeech.VERB,
    'remove': PartOfSpeech.VERB,
    'chat': PartOfSpeech.VERB,
    'accept': PartOfSpeech.VERB,
    'active': PartOfSpeech.VERB,
    'suspend': PartOfSpeech.VERB,
    'construct': PartOfSpeech.VERB,
    'close': PartOfSpeech.VERB,
    'add': PartOfSpeech.VERB,

    //NOUNS
    'project': PartOfSpeech.NOUN,
    'user': PartOfSpeech.NOUN,
    'task': PartOfSpeech.NOUN,
    'chat': PartOfSpeech.NOUN,
    'conversation': PartOfSpeech.NOUN,

    //DETERMINERS
    'a': PartOfSpeech.DETERMINER,
    'the': PartOfSpeech.DETERMINER,

    //PREPOSITIONS
    'to': PartOfSpeech.PREPOSITION,
    'from': PartOfSpeech.PREPOSITION,
    'for': PartOfSpeech.PREPOSITION,
    'with': PartOfSpeech.PREPOSITION    
    ]


//constructor
def PartOfSpeechTagger()
{

}

def tagWords(String[] words)
{
    def taggedWords = [] as ArrayList
    words.each{
        //removing the use of 'it' due to nested closures
        println"word to search for : ${it}"
        def word = it
        if(inLexicons(word))
        {
            println"word :: ${it}"
            taggedWords.add(
                new TaggedWord(
                    lexicons.find{it.key == word}.key, 
                    lexicons.find{it.key == word}.value)
                )           
        }
        else
        {
            /* 
             * handle errors for not finding a word?
             */
        }
    }   

    return taggedWords
}

def inLexicons(key)
{
    return lexicons.containsKey(key)
}   
}
```

you can see in the `tagWords` method where I want to be able to report back to the client that a word that was supplied was not expected.

Comment: So, what's the question?

Comment: I want to know the best way of creating error messages and the best way to send them back to the client.  Do I create my own exceptions?

Comment: So in an ajax call you can return an error code and text. Example: `response.status = 400` `render "Could not match a tag"`.

Comment: @JamesKleeh , thanks this seems to be what Im after.  I can get the 400 status code at the client, though I can't find where I can receive the text that has been rendered?

Comment: got it..XMLHttpRequest.responseText   Thanks for your help

Comment: @andymccullough Please post it as answer, it will help on localize this question as answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it working,

In the controller

```
render(status: 400, text: "the message")
```

then in my remote form

```
onFailure="doSomething(XMLHttpRequest)"
```

then accessed this in javascript by

```
XMLHttpRequest.responseText
```